# Как регулярными выражениями вытащить путь к субдиректории?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть txt-файл, в котором есть такие ссылки:

```
http://mysite.net/components/com_jcomments/...
http://mysite.net/components/com_other_stuff/...
```

Как регулярными выражениями найти все все эти `/com_.../` .  Ведь на момент поиска известно , что эта директория начинается одинаково, то есть с `com_`.
То есть в результате работы регулярного выражения у меня должно получиться:

```
/com_jcomments
/com_other_stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До меня дошло:

```
def look_for_comp(li):
    out_file=open('the_site.txt','r',encoding='Latin-1')
    mytext=out_file.read()
    result = re.findall(r'/com_\S[^\/]+', mytext)
    print (result)
```